# Looking for distance of two location (lat, lng) with st_distance postgresql

Tags: postgresql, distance

i try to get distance two point of `(-7.4379722 109.2442663)` and `(-7.4201487 109.245204)`

I am using this query:

```
select st_distance(
    st_geomfromtext('POINT(-7.4379722 109.2442663)'), 
    st_geomfromtext('POINT(-7.4201487 109.245204)')
)
```

and return of query :

```
0.0178481493029382 meters
```

and looking on google this is `2,59 KM`

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rahrb.png

what i should i do ?

Comment: These two distances have nothing in common with each other.  I also doubt that Google would be very far from the truth, which leaves your API call as being the problem.

Comment: yes right, only approaches can be sought, not specific results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The coordinates must be expressed using longitude first, then latitude.

If you compute a distance using lat-long geometries, the output would be in degrees (which is not a good unit for distances). Instead, you can use the geography data type, which use meters

```
select st_distance(
    st_geogfromtext('POINT( 109.2442663 -7.4379722)'), 
    st_geogfromtext('POINT( 109.245204 -7.4201487)')
);
  st_distance
---------------
 1973.86761798
(1 row)
```

Comment: thanks for correct me, the result is close to the original distance, the result is close to the original distance, the difference is only about 100 meters for this case